# key does not exist in style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i am learning trigger in `WPF`. from here [trigger demo](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/522041/Triggers-in-WPF)
but when i write code similar to that tutorial then it show "**the property key does not exist**"

my code

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Content="My Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxWidth="100" Padding="6" Margin="8"/>

    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

K in key needs to be in capital `x:Key`

Make sure you have included the namespace 'x'

`xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"` in the Windows tag